# Can someone help me resolve the Word online error SP Online shown in below screenshot?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

I am trying to open a word file in Word online and I am getting the below error. This happens in all browsers. I am working with SharePoint online/Office 365 and cant really find a solution for this, can someone help me resolve this.

Please note that the document is editable in word desktop not in the online version.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have an issue with SSL. Either the certificate chain isn't available/valid on SharePoint or the Office Web Apps farm can't resolve the Web App's URL back to SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

Did you can open the word file in word online before?

Did the issue only occur in the word file or all word files?

If the issue only occurs in one word file, you could check things below:

1. Clear the IE cache.
2. Delete the word file and re-upload the word file.
3. Upload a new file to check if the same issue will occur.

If the issue occurs in all files, then you could submit a service request like the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The issue seems to occur only with one file. It still persists, I guess I will just open a case with microsoft and troubleshoot this more.

Comment: Ok, you can open  a case.